# vim: How to create a key binding that insert a piece of text?

Tags: vim

I want to create a key binding that insert a piece of text in the code, for example "hi".

I tried adding this to my .vimrc file:

```
map gp :hi
```

but it doesnt work..

Any idea?

Javi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three approaches shown in this answer for inserting text with shortcuts. The first one is for mapping in normal mode, the second inserting abbreviations in insert mode, and the third for abbreviations in command mode.

Additionally, you can take a look to plugins like [`snipmate`](https://github.com/msanders/snipmate.vim)

---

## 1. Insert text from normal mode and return to normal

`:nnoremap gp iHi<Esc>`

---

## 2. Change 'hi' to 'hello' and keep in insert mode

Abbreviations in insert mode are:

`:iab hi Hello`  (test it typing *hi* followed by <kbd>spacebar</kbd>)

if you like to insert a month list:

`:iab mOn Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec`

if you want a shortcut for including stdio.h

`:iab inC #include <stdio.h>`

---

## 3. Abbreviations in command mode

`:ab hi Hello`

A practical example, using e.g. `wsu` for saving the current file with superuser credentials.

`:ab wsu w !sudo tee %`

Comment: sorry, but i don't understand exactly what you mean.. I have written 'map gp :iab Hello' to my .vimrc, but when I press 'gp' doesn't add Hello to the code...It just add ':iab Hello' to the command line. All that being in command model.

Comment: @user1077220 Made an edit to clarity those where different options you can choose. Please, type it as shown in the answer without mixing them.